# Cancelling a context with custom error in Go

Tags: go

I create cancellable Go context and I need to cancel it from time to time. Yet, the standard "context cancelled" error message does not seem quite informative to me. I would like to make custom one. But there is no clear way to do that! When you open `context` package sources, particularly `WithCancel` function, you see that the error `Cancelled` is used but actually there's no reason why custom error object is not an argument of `CancelFunc`.

The question is, is there a concise way to create cancellable context with custom cancel error message in Go, without copy-pasting `WithCancel` source code?

Comment: Context is an interface. You can implement it however you'd like.

Comment: I guess it's the copy-paste answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your case, but it sounds like [CancelCauseFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/context#CancelCauseFunc) and [WithCancelCause](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancelCause) would fit the bill.

Comment: Just FYI; `WithCancelCause` was introduced in Go 1.20, so was not available when the question was asked (it does appear to address the OP's requirement).

Comment: You are correct. I realized only after I commented that this was an old question -- it rolled up via the "Unanswered" filter, and I didn't notice the date before. I left the comment in hopes it might still be useful.

Comment: Thanks, happy to know this issue was fixed!